# How to configure postfix client on port 465?

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, smtps

I installed postfix on a server, but port 25 was blocked by ISP. I followed http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_smtps to configure smtps on port 465.
I follow the configuration as `Postfix ≥ 3.0: Sending only mail for a specific destination via SMTPS`,
But I have to add mail domain to /etc/postfix/transport.

```
a.com  relay-smtps:mx.a.com:465
b.com relay-smtps:mx.b.com:465
```

part of /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_security_level = may
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

part of /etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
relay-smtps  unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    # Client-side SMTPS requires "encrypt" or stronger.
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes
```

For destination not in transport, postfix tries connect to port 25.

I can only send email to destination listed in transport.

How do I change the postfix so that it tries send all emails to `[their own DNS MX record]:465` ?
I have tried `Postfix ≥ 3.0: Sending all remote mail to an SMTPS server`:

```
relayhost = [mx.a.com]:465
```

But it was regarded as spam.

If I do like:

```
mydomain.com :
* relay-smtps:how can use DNS MX recode auto:465
```

How can I specify port 465 and use DNS MX record?

Thanks!